# MySQL - create new row and insert existing data with new ID?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table similar to the following, is it possible to:

1) copy the existing "value" found adjacent to "type = 42" 
2) insert a new row at the end of each record (append) 
3) add the value found in "type = 42" to the the new row but change the type from 42 to "206"? as shown below, BEFORE and AFTER.

Is this possible?

BEFORE:

```
+-------+------+-------+---------+---------+
|  id   | name | abbr  | type    | value   |
+-------+------+-------+---------+---------+
|  123  | HCT  | HCT   | 42      | XYZ     |
|       |      |       | 57      | ABC     |
|       |      |       | 131     | RST     |
|       |      |       | 208     | 110     |
|  358  | CBC  | CBC   | 42      | 9AB     |
|       |      |       | 32      | GHI     |
|       |      |       | 11      | SB1     |
|       |      |       | 22      | LLY     |
|       |      |       | 57      | JKL     |
|       |      |       | 131     | 32B     |
|       |      |       | 263     | POF     |
|  102  | BMP  | BMP   | 42      | 444     |
|       |      |       | 131     | 09N     |
|       |      |       | 263     | 77M     |
|       |      |       | 35      | XJJ     |
|       |      |       | 11      | X10     |
|       |      |       | 22      | PLP     |
+-------+------+-------+---------+---------+
```

AFTER:

```
+-------+------+-------+---------+---------+
|  id   | name | abbr  | id_type | id_base |
+-------+------+-------+---------+---------+
|  123  | HCT  | HCT   | 42      | XYZ     |
|       |      |       | 57      | ABC     |
|       |      |       | 131     | RST     |
|       |      |       | 208     | 110     |
|       |      |       | 206     | XYZ     |
|  358  | CBC  | CBC   | 42      | 9AB     |
|       |      |       | 32      | GHI     |
|       |      |       | 11      | SB1     |
|       |      |       | 22      | LLY     |
|       |      |       | 57      | JKL     |
|       |      |       | 131     | 32B     |
|       |      |       | 263     | POF     |
|       |      |       | 206     | 9AB     |
|  102  | BMP  | BMP   | 42      | 444     |
|       |      |       | 131     | 09N     |
|       |      |       | 263     | 77M     |
|       |      |       | 35      | XJJ     |
|       |      |       | 11      | X10     |
|       |      |       | 22      | PLP     |
|       |      |       | 206     | 444     |
+-------+------+-------+---------+---------+
```

Thank you for any help!

I'm new to MySQL.

Comment: Please add schema and sample data.

Comment: Without a PRIMARY KEY, any such attempt would be meaningless

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) query to do this:

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT id, name, abbr, 206, value
FROM table1
WHERE type = 42
```

Note that I've assumed you want to copy the `id`, `name` and `abbr` values from the row with `type=42`. If you want them to be blank (as in your sample data), change the query to

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT '', '', '', 206, value
FROM table1
WHERE type = 42
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dVZ6AVGaThQYuKSEfYDUpH/0)

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Comment: Thank you Nick for the help. So, I originally thought I would need to load my csv file into a SQL database to 'INSERT INTO' based on an existing value, but now I'm wondering if I need a database to accomplish my goal? I have the following flat file which contains two records

Comment: The following contains two records 'id, 23' and 'id, 358', is there a way to insert the value found in 'id_type, 42, id_base, 206,'? without using SQL database?

id,
123,
name,
HCT,
abbr,
HCT,
id_type,
42,
id_base,
XYZ,
id_type,
57,
id_base,
ABC,
id_type,
131,
id_base,
RST,
id_type,
208,
id_base,
110,
id,
358,
name,
CBC,
abbr,
CBC,
id_type,
42,
id_base,
9AB,
id_type,
32,
id_base,
GHI,
id_type,
11,
id_base,
SB1,
id_type,
22,
id_base,
LLY,
id_type,
57,
id_base,
JKL,
id_type,
131,
id_base,
32B,

Comment: @JackLabatt I would say you probably don't need a database. You should ask a new question along the lines of these comments and then you can use whichever solution works best for you.